# Cómo hago para que no sobrepase el header

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estoy creando unas imágenes escalables, pero cuando subo la página y posiciono el puntero el escalable sobrepasa el `header` y no quiero eso.

Les muestro el CSS q tengo, el HTML solo es un `section`, `article` e `img`, nada más; donde está el trabajo es en el CSS:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open sans';
  background: #E8E8E8;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  padding: 1%;
  background: #21618c;
  z-index: 100px;
}

header #button-menu {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navegacion {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
}

.navegacion ul {
  width: 320px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -320px;
  transition: left .3s;
}

.navegacion .menu li.title-menu {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #5F6F81;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.navegacion .menu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C6D0DA;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #575D69;
}

.navegacion .menu a:hover {
  background: #798DA3;
  color: #fff;
}

.navegacion .menu li span.icon-menu {
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.navegacion .menu .item-submenu>a::after {
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  content: '\f105';
  float: right;
  color: #C5C5C5;
}


/* Submenu ============*/

.navegacion .submenu li.title-menu {
  background: #fff;
  color: #575D69;
}

.navegacion .submenu li.go-back {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #5F6F81;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navegacion .submenu li.go-back::before {
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  content: '\f0d9';
  margin-right: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .navegacion ul {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/* ============================   Footer ===========================*/

footer {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  background: #21618c;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}


/*  %%%%%%%%%   Contenido   %%%%%%%%%   */

#article img {
  margin-top: 3%;
  width: 11%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 5%;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

#article img:hover {
  z-index: -1;
  transform: scale(3.2, 3.2);
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}


/*  %%%%%%%%%%  menu lateral  %%%%%%%%%%  */

#menu {
  display: block;
  width: 10%;
  height: 60vh;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  background: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 3vh;
  color: #fff;
}

#menu h2 {
  font-size: 3vh;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#menu ul li {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  width: 90%;
  background: #21618c;
  padding: 1%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10% 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 10%;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

#menu ul li:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

#menu ul #logolateral {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
}

#buscar {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-top: 7%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  padding: 1%;
  outline: none;
  width: 75%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="iso-8859-1"/>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab" rel="stylesheet">

<header>
  <span id="button-menu" class="fa fa-bars"></span>
  <nav class="navegacion">
    <ul class="menu">
      <!-- TITULAR -->
      <li class="title-menu">Bienvenido</li>
      <!-- TITULAR -->
      <li><a href="/index.html"><span class="fa fa-home icon-menu"></span>Inicio</a></li>
      <li class="item-submenu" menu="1">
        <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-folder icon-menu"></span>Unidad 1</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="title-menu"><span class="fa fa-folder-open icon-menu"></span>Unidad 1</li>
          <li class="go-back">Atras</li>
          <li><a href="#">Plataformas Web</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Estructura Web</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Internet de las cosas</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Servidores Web</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Maquetacion</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-submenu" menu="2">
        <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-folder icon-menu"></span>Unidad 2</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="title-menu"><span class="fa fa-folder-open icon-menu"></span>Unidad 2</li>
          <li class="go-back">Atras</li>
          <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Encuesta</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">PDF</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Registro</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-submenu" menu='3'>
        <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-folder icon-menu"></span>Unidad 3</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="title-menu"><span class="fa fa-folder-open icon-menu">Unidad 3</span></li>
          <li class="go-back">Atras</li>
          <li><a href="#">Paginas en construcion</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-submenu" menu='4'>
        <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-folder icon-menu"></span>Unidad 4</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="title-menu"><span class="fa fa-folder-open icon-menu">Unidad 4</span></li>
          <li class="go-back">Atras</li>
          <li><a href="#">Paginas en construcion</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-submenu" menu='5'>
        <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-folder icon-menu"></span>Unidad 5</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="title-menu"><span class="fa fa-folder-open icon-menu">Unidad 5</span></li>
          <li class="go-back">Atras</li>
          <li><a href="#">Paginas en construcion</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-submenu" menu='6'>
        <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-shopping-bag icon-menu"></span>Tienda</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<section id="section">
  <input id="buscar" type="text" placeholder="Buscar">
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <img id="logolateral" src="img/logo.png" alt="">
      <li><a href="">Adidas</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Nike</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Puma</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <article id="article">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" onclick="">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" onclick="">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" onclick="">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" onclick="">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" onclick="">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" onclick="">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" onclick="">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" onclick="">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" onclick="">
  </article>
</section>

<footer>
  <p>Derechos reservados </p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Incluye tu código html para poder reproducir el problema

Comment: listo ya lo agrege pero aun asi no lo ejecuta

Comment: ¿Estas seguro de que ese es el CSS que estás utilizando? He copiado tu código y no parece que tenga el error que indicas: **https://jsfiddle.net/s9q1s25L/**

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que sobrepasa el header? El código compartido no tiene ningún header, ¿podrías añadir el código necesario para reproducir el problema y añadir una mejor descripción del mismo?

Comment: http://miestilo.onlinewebshop.net/    ve ese link y sabras del problema que tengo. Bajas la pagina y posicionas el mouse en la primera linea de imagenes y veras como se sobre ponen del header

Comment: Aún así, deberías incluir el header dentro del HTML de tu pregunta

Comment: @Lovato no puedo acceder a esa página (el cortafuegos me lo impide), si pudieras añadir el código a la pregunta directamente para que pueda ver el problema, te echo un cable en un momento.

Comment: https://mega.nz/#!ewUxRaCK!qlHMPEOuCa19D-LGxUDi5raxylpa6QebZQ_sbdWCGi8    ahi esta el archivo @AlvaroMontoro por si gustas ayudarme te lo agradezco mucho desde ya

Comment: @Lovato mega.nz está cortado también por el firewall. Por favor, añade el código en la pregunta directamente en lugar de un sitio externo.

Comment: La pregunta debe contener todo lo necesario para replicar el error. Si la página "de prueba" deja de existir el próximo año, quien llegue a leer la pregunta no va a poder usarla.

Comment: ya lo actualize pero como no existe ninguna imagen almacenada no se puede ver el error q me genera solo el del footer

Comment: Hola @Lovato, he editado la pregunta para reducir el código y añadirle las bibliotecas y las imágenes que faltaban para que se pueda ver el problema. ¿Podrías describir mejor qué es lo que no funciona? No termina de quedarme claro después de ver el código corriendo. ¿Cuál es el problema del `header` y del `footer`?

Comment: el problema del header es que cuando yo coloco el puntero sobre una imagen el scale que le coloque, se pone sobre encima del header, y eso es algo que no quiero que suceda, e tenido que cambiar de estilo ya que si me quedo esperando no are nada.

Comment: Hola @Lovato, he _exagerado_ la animación para que se vea el problema porque antes no se veía. Ahora ya se puede ver que la imagen queda por debajo del `footer` (aunque parece que se ve bien por encima del `header`). Si es sólo eso, se soluciona poniéndole `z-index:-1;` al `footer``

Answer (score 1):

el CSS del header tiene definido el z-index en pixeles. Ese índice (index) va sin unidades de medida, así:

```
z-index: 99999;
```